# Do scanf and getchar handle stream differently?

Tags: c, io, scanf, getchar

I'm confused about how scanf and getchar handle stream differently, the following is a sample code:

```
while(scanf("%d", &input) != 1)
{
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    printf("\nThis is wrong\n");
}

printf("That is right\n");
```

It is a simple program used to test if the input is a integer. The inner while loop is used to display every wrong input value before click Enter. When I entered a random string such as:

```
qwert
```

putchar will print out the exact string. However, if I replaced

```
while(scanf("%d", &input) != 1)
```

with

```
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
```

and print out the exact same string, the first letter "q" is dropped out.
So my question is how do scanf and getchar in the outer loop handle this situation differently?

Comment: `getchar` in the outer loop eats up the `q`. Add `putchar(ch)` just before the inner loop to fix the issue. On the other hand, `scanf("%d")` , on invalid input such as a character, will fail, and return 0, leaving the character (invalid input) in the `stdin` itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `scanf` to try and read an integer, and you give some input that is *not* an integer, then `scanf` will fail and not return `1`. It will however leave the input intact, it won't extract anything from the input, leaving it all for your inner loop to digest and print.

If you use `getchar` in the outer loop, it will actually consume a single character, no matter what character it is, and the inner loop will then not see that character since it doesn't exist in the input buffer anymore.